# How to generate all possible combinations

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
Folder Prey has 
    "Deer.txt",
    "Antelope.txt",
    "Rabbit.txt"  
Folder Predator has 
    "Shark.txt",
    "Bear.txt",
    "Cougar.txt"  
Folder Habitat has 
    "Forest.txt",
    "Ocean.txt",
    "Desert.txt"
```

How do I generate all 27 possible combinations using a .bat file?
The tricky part is the number of Folders is not static.  Someone may add a Folder Food later, or remove Folder Habitat.
Could a .bat file be written to handle this?

The output would be:

```
Deer_Shark_Forest
Deer_Shark_Ocean
Deer_Shark_Desert
Deer_Bear_Forest
Deer_Bear_Ocean
Deer_Bear_Desert
Deer_Cougar_Forest
Deer_Cougar_Ocean
Deer_Cougar_Desert
Antelope_Shark_Forest
Antelope_Shark_Ocean
Antelope_Shark_Desert
Antelope_Bear_Forest
Antelope_Bear_Ocean
Antelope_Bear_Desert
Antelope_Cougar_Forest
Antelope_Cougar_Ocean
Antelope_Cougar_Desert
Rabbit_Shark_Forest
Rabbit_Shark_Ocean
Rabbit_Shark_Desert
Rabbit_Bear_Forest
Rabbit_Bear_Ocean
Rabbit_Bear_Desert
Rabbit_Cougar_Forest
Rabbit_Cougar_Ocean
Rabbit_Cougar_Desert
```

Assure you this is not a homework question.
I'd like to write it as a batch file.

Comment: What do you mean by "all possible combinations"? Please [edit] your question to show an example output and include what you have tried so far.

Comment: This very much sounds like a homework question.

Comment: I've tried nested For loops, but that has a limitation.  The number of Folders is determined at compile time, and not at runtime.  I would like to have the ability to add or remove folders.

Comment: The example has 3 folders of 3 items each, or 27 combinations.

Comment: A folder holds files.  You're showing a list of text values.  Please clarify exactly what the source is.

Comment: The filename and the file's contents are identical.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set first_pass=yes
copy nul temp2.txt > nul
for /d %%D in (*) do (
    for %%F in ("%%D"\*) do (
        if !first_pass! == yes (
            echo %%~nF >> temp2.txt
        ) else (
            for /f "delims=" %%L in (temp1.txt) do (
                echo %%~nF_%%L >> temp2.txt
            )
        )
    )
    set first_pass=no
    del temp1.txt 2> nul
    rename temp2.txt temp1.txt
)
```

This creates a file named `temp1.txt`. 
(Of course the script can trivially be modified to use a different filename
and/or to display the results on the screen.) 
This is the output I got:

```
Antelope_Bear_Desert
Antelope_Bear_Forest
Antelope_Bear_Ocean
Antelope_Cougar_Desert
Antelope_Cougar_Forest
Antelope_Cougar_Ocean
Antelope_Shark_Desert
Antelope_Shark_Forest
Antelope_Shark_Ocean
Deer_Bear_Desert
Deer_Bear_Forest
Deer_Bear_Ocean
Deer_Cougar_Desert
Deer_Cougar_Forest
Deer_Cougar_Ocean
Deer_Shark_Desert
Deer_Shark_Forest
Deer_Shark_Ocean
Rabbit_Bear_Desert
Rabbit_Bear_Forest
Rabbit_Bear_Ocean
Rabbit_Cougar_Desert
Rabbit_Cougar_Forest
Rabbit_Cougar_Ocean
Rabbit_Shark_Desert
Rabbit_Shark_Forest
Rabbit_Shark_Ocean
```

Notes:

- Obviously, this uses the `*` wildcard,
  and so the order of the output depends on the order
  in which Windows expands the wildcard. 
  On my system, given alphabetic directory entries,
  `*` is expanded in alphabetic order. 
  This may be different on systems that use languages other than English,
  and/or it may be changeable by configuration setting. 
  For the purpose of the next two bullets,
  I will assume that alphabetic order is used.
- Within each folder, the names are in alphabetic order;
  e.g., Antelope before Deer, etc…, Bear before Cougar, etc…, etc…
- In accordance with your desired output specified in your question,
  the *folders* are output in *reverse* alphabetic order;
  i.e., Prey_Predator_Habitat.
- Either of the above can be changed (although not elegantly).

- `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` lets us handle variables in loops.
- `copy nul temp2.txt > nul` creates the second temporary working file. 
  The `> nul` suppresses the normal `1 file(s) copied.` status message.
- `for /d %%D in (*) do` loops through all the folders
  in the current directory. 
  The variable `%%D` will sequentially take on the values
  `Habitat`, `Predator`, and `Prey` —
  or whatever folders are in the current directory
  when you run the batch file.
- `for %%F in ("%%D"\*) do` loops through all the files in directory `%%D`;
  i.e., the directory we’re currently looking at from the outer loop. 
  The variable `%%F` will sequentially take on values such as
  `Habitat\Desert.txt`, `Habitat\Forest.txt`, and `Habitat\Ocean.txt`. 
  The quotes allow this to work even if the directory name contains space(s).

  If there are other files in the folder, they will be included, too. 
  If you want to look only at `.txt` files,
  change the `for` statement to `for %%F in ("%%D"\*.txt) do`.
- `!first_pass!` is just the variable `first_pass`. 
  It would normally be written `%first_pass%`,
  but we need to use this syntax because we’re in a loop. 
  (This works only because we enabled it,
  with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.)
- `first_pass` is `yes` while we are processing the first directory;
  i.e., `Habitat`. 
  In this case we just write the filename to the `temp2.txt` file;
  so, when the `for %%F in ("%%D"\*) do` loop completes, `temp2.txt`
  will contain

  ```
  Desert
  Forest
  Ocean
  ```

  because `%%~nF`
  evaluates to only the base file **n**ame part of the file pathname in `%%F`. 
  If you want to include the `.txt` e**x**tensions,
  use `%%~nxF` instead of `%%~nF`.
- Spoiler alert: when we execute the outer (`for /d %%D`)
  for the second and third (etc.) time, `first_pass` is `no`
  and `temp1.txt` is the `temp2.txt` from the previous pass.
- So, on the second and third (etc.) passes,
  we execute `for /f "delims=" %%L in (temp1.txt) do`,
  which loops through the *lines* in `temp1.txt`,
  setting `%%L` to the contents of the lines.
  `"delims="` is an *options* string that specifies that the lines
  should not be broken into words. 
  This allows this batch file to work even if the file names contain space(s).
- For example, on the second pass (`%%D`=`Predator`) of the outer loop,
  when we do the first pass (`%%F`=`Predator\Bear.txt`) of the second loop,
  `temp1.txt` is as shown above for `temp2.txt`, and `temp2.txt` is empty.
- For each line (`%%L`) from `temp1.txt`,
  we do `echo %%~nF_%%L >> temp2.txt`,
  which writes the current filename, an underscore `_`,
  and the current line (from `temp1.txt`) into `temp2.txt` (appending). 
  Thus, after the first pass (`Bear`) of the second loop,
  including a complete run of the third loop, `temp2.txt`
  will contain

  ```
  Bear_Desert
  Bear_Forest
  Bear_Ocean
  ```

  The second pass (`Cougar`) of the second loop will append

  ```
  Cougar_Desert
  Cougar_Forest
  Cougar_Ocean
  ```

  to `temp2.txt`,
  and so on.
- By the time we reach the third pass (`%%D`=`Prey`) of the outer loop,
  `temp1.txt` is the `temp2.txt` from the previous pass,
  containing nine lines (six of which are shown above). 
  Then the same thing happens (with different values) as before;
  `%%F` gets set to `Prey\Antelope.txt`,
  and so every line in `temp1.txt` gets copied to `temp2.txt`
  with `Antelope_` prepended, and we get

  ```
  Antelope_Bear_Desert
  Antelope_Bear_Forest
  Antelope_Bear_Ocean
  Antelope_Cougar_Desert
  Antelope_Cougar_Forest
         ︙
  ```
- As foreshadowed, when we finish the second loop,
  and get to the end of the first loop,
  we set `first_pass` to `no`,
  delete the current `temp1.txt`
  (if any; if it doesn’t exist yet, suppress the error message),
  and rename `temp2.txt` to `temp1.txt`.

So, we end up with a file 27 lines long
(Num(`Habitat`) × Num(`Predator`) × Num(`Prey`)).
You can add and remove folders and files,
because nothing is hard-coded in the script —
not even the number of folders.

- If there is a folder (e.g., `Job_Titles`) that contains no files,
  then there will be no output (because 3 × 0 × 3 × 3 = 0). 
  In fact,
  in this case, the above batch file produces a bunch of error messages,
  and either an empty `temp1.txt` file (expected behavior) or no file at all. 
  This can of course be fixed.
- This script has been designed to handle file or directory names
  that contain space(s),
  and has been tested in that situation (and it seems to work correctly),
  but there may be some edge cases that I didn’t consider.
- Inevitably, the output will be ambiguous
  if any of the file names contain `_` (underscore). 
  For example, `Antelope_Mountain_Lion_Forest` is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell:

```
$categories = gci -Directory | % {$_.Name}
Function AddCombos([int]$catPos, $root) {
    gci ".\$($categories[$catPos])\*.txt" | % {
        $memberTitle = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name)
        If ($catPos -eq ($categories.Length - 1)) {
            $root + $memberTitle
        } Else {
            AddCombos ($catpos + 1) ($root + $memberTitle + '_')
        }
    }
}
AddCombos 0 ''
```

First, this script gets the names of all the categories (e.g. "Prey") and puts them in the `$categories` list. It then defines a recursive function. `AddCombos` gets all the files in the category indexed by `$catPos`. If it's not on the last category, it outputs the completed string. Otherwise, it calls itself after adding the current member (e.g. "Deer") to the work-in-progress string and incrementing `$catPos` to indicate that the next category should be looked at. After defining that function, the script calls it starting at the first category (index 0) and with an empty string as the work-in-progress.

Note that the order of the categories is determined alphabetically. Since the folder names aren't used in the output, you can name them such that they'll be done in the order you desire. The script uses the text files' titles in the output, but if you want to control the order of those by renaming the files, you can change the `$memberTitle =` line to this:

```
$memberTitle = (gc $_)[0]
```

That takes the first line of each file's contents instead of its title.

This script can handle any number of categories and any number of members in each category.

To run it, save it as a `.ps1` file and follow the instructions in the Enabling Scripts section of [the PowerShell tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/powershell/info). Then you can run it from a batch file like this:

```
powershell .\myscript.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%t in ("%temp%\%random%%random%%random%.tmp") do (
        >"%%~ft" echo(*
        for /d %%d in (*) do >nul 2>&1 dir /a-d "%%d" && for /f "tokens=* delims=*" %%l in ('
            type "%%~ft" ^& ^>"%%~ft" break
        ') do for %%f in ("%%d\*") do (
            >>"%%~ft" (if "%%~l"=="" (echo(%%~nf) else (echo %%l_%%~nf))
        )
    ) & type "%%~ft" & del "%%~ft"
```

It will generate a temporary file (referenced by `%%t`) where to concatenate the output lines.

For each directory (`%%d`) the temporary file is readed, cleared and for each line (`%%l`) in the temporary file it is echoed again with each file (`%%f`) under the current folder concatenated

Once all the files names have been concatenated, the temporary file is sent to console and removed.